# change meta while saving in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

i added metaboxes to my custom post. how can i change a meta while saving. for example change a URL or read the site name and save it to another hidden meta?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a hidden input inside the custom post type as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="variable" style="display:none;" readonly>
```

At the same time 
Try below code:

On same page you can get form field and insert into db:

you can further use generated post id for save custom meta.

```
if(isset($_POST['variable'])){
$var = $_POST['variable']; 
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', $var); 
}
```